# how to delete first IntNode

Tags: c#

```
class IntNode
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public IntNode next { get; set; }

        public IntNode(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = null;
        }
        public IntNode(int value, IntNode next)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
        public bool HasNext()
        {
            return (next != null);
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (this.HasNext())
                return value + "-->" + next;
            else
                return value + "";
        }
    }
```

so if I wanted to remove the 4th node with given list starts with head:

```
IntNode pos = head.next;
IntNode prev = head;
int counter = 0;
while (pos != null)
{
    if (counter == 4) prev.next = pos.next;
    prev = pos;
    pos = pos.next;
}
```

But I want to remove the first node (when counter is 0).  How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You need a Root node so you can delete the first item.  Learned that 40 years ago in CS201.

Comment: Looks like you're not incrementing your counter

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for you:

```
while (pos != null)
{
   if ( counter == 0 )
   {
      head = head.next;
      prev = head;
   }
   else
   {
      prev.next = pos.next;
   }
}
```

Comment: But when I print the list (after this function) it shows the first number even if it was deleted. The only case it will work with is if I will print head.next but it isn`t good because I am not always deleting the first node.

Comment: I guess I'd have to see your print function, then, and how that's walking the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Remove(int index) {
    if(head != null)
    {
        if(index == 0)
        {
            head = head.next;
        }
        else
        {
            IntNode pos = head.next;
            IntNode prev = head;
            while (pos != null)
            {
                --index;
                if (index == 0)
                {
                    prev.next = pos.next;
                    break;
                }
                prev = pos;
                pos = pos.next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working, because if I have 1->2->3->4 and the function gets head (not index, because you should get the list) so head will be head.next only in the function and not outside (tested it)

Comment: I believe you misunderstood... This function is meant to be defined in the class where head is defined so that it can directly change the value of head...